# jQuery - Multi-Level Nested ul sub-menus on hover

Tags: jquery, menu, nested, html-lists, submenu

After trying various approaches and examples for the past few hours, I'm having trouble finding a clean jQuery method of opening the sub-menus for a products nav menu. The nav items are pulled from a custom Walker class in WordPress.

The idea is that hovering "Products" opens the "Product Groups" level below, then hovering the products group opens it's sub-menu to it's right (if it has a next level - might just be product info). I have it working for the top level using first().fadeToggle - I've set up a JSFiddle for example: https://jsfiddle.net/yvu237t2/4/

```
$( "ul#productnav" ).hover(function() {
  $( "ul.sub-menu" ).first().fadeToggle("fast");
});
```

I'm stuck on figuring out the syntax for locating and opening the next sub level, based on hovering the level before it.

Any insight, much appreciated.

Here is a design comp of the end result for reference:

[image: Sample comp for the nav menu]

If there is only one product in the main group, then it would be nested like: 
[image: Sample comp for when only one product is nested inside of the parent group]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yvu237t2/5/   heh, playing around with the hover on the sub menus.  Not complete, but maybe it will give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks @Taplar - that helps to see. I tried implementing this to select the next level down, while keeping the parents active, but having trouble with it. Is there a similar way to grab next levels down (if they exist) in the same method? https://jsfiddle.net/yvu237t2/6/

Answer (score 0):

What I was trying to track down was using the children() selector - posting here for reference in case this helps anyone else looking for something similar.

```
$( 'ul#productnav li' ).hover(function() {
  $( this ).children( 'ul' ).toggleClass('active');
});
```